# cakephp 3.x: single input in two records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables:

```
cases 
  - id
  - office_residence
  - district_offices_id
```

and

```
district_offices
  - id
  - other_field
```

I want to save both records with this single input.

The user only inputs `office_residence`.

The controller was baked by the console.

The view to add a case includes:

```
echo $this->Form->input('office_residence', array('options' => $district_offices));
```

I have no idea how to save this single input in the two records. Please help a newbie-fool. ;)

Comment: Why do you have fields `cases.office_residence` and `cases.district_offices_id`? Are they not redundant? What do you want to store in  `cases.office_residence`?

Comment: You´re completely right. Sometimes my mind is so complicated, I´m not able to see the simplest solution. XD Thanks so much. :)